# How can I relocate my magento store's media directory?

Tags: magento

I would like to move the media directory in for my magento store to a different drive on the server.

Looking at `app/etc/config.xml` I see an xml field:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <filesystem>
            <media>{{root_dir}}/media</media>
        </filesystem>
    </default>
</config>
```

I would expect that I could change that value to the new directory's location and all would be good.

However, looking at `code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php`, I see that the media directory is defined as `$root.DS.'media';` rather than from the xml config:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $appRoot= Mage::getRoot();
    $root   = dirname($appRoot);

    $this->_data['app_dir']     = $appRoot;
    $this->_data['base_dir']    = $root;
    $this->_data['code_dir']    = $appRoot.DS.'code';
    $this->_data['design_dir']  = $appRoot.DS.'design';
    $this->_data['etc_dir']     = $appRoot.DS.'etc';
    $this->_data['lib_dir']     = $root.DS.'lib';
    $this->_data['locale_dir']  = $appRoot.DS.'locale';
    $this->_data['media_dir']   = $root.DS.'media';
    $this->_data['skin_dir']    = $root.DS.'skin';
    $this->_data['var_dir']     = $this->getVarDir();
    $this->_data['tmp_dir']     = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'tmp';
    $this->_data['cache_dir']   = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'cache';
    $this->_data['log_dir']     = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'log';
    $this->_data['session_dir'] = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'session';
    $this->_data['upload_dir']  = $this->_data['media_dir'].DS.'upload';
    $this->_data['export_dir']  = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'export';
}
```

Wouldn't this mean that any change I make to `config.xml` would have no effect on my actual configuration?

I'm also aware that this directory will need to be web-accessable, and that I will need to configure the Base Media URL through the magento admin tools to point to this new directory.  I plan to set this new directory as a sub-domain, and set the Base Media URLs to this sub-domain.

Does anyone have any experience with moving the media directory?

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunate that the config *appears* to be there, but the values are hardcoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done at the OS level, no need to mess with Magento. Just create a `symlink`

```
ln -s /my/real/path/to/media /my/path/to/magento/media
```

Comment: No this will fail because tinyMCE will make bad URLs in the WYIWYG editor if the media directory is symlinked to somewhere else.

Comment: @CommaToast - elaborate how exactly? A symlink is server-side and tinyMCE is client side. A symlink is transparent to a web browser and shouldn't affect anything client side, as far as it is concerned - it is going into a dir called `media`

Answer (score 2):

Can add as symbol links,
but you will get some problem with WYSIWYG editor in admin panel :)

Need following:

edit **/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php**

***function getCurrentUrl()***

```
$path = str_replace(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir(), '', $this->getCurrentPath());
```

change to

```
$path = str_replace(realpath(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir()), '', $this->getCurrentPath());
```

Comment: That is only a partial solution though because creating folders will still be broken in the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, why hack Magento's code when it's all actually a web server configuration combined with proper entries in the url fields in the Magento backend?

The subdomain is easily taken care of with a CNAME entry in your DNS to point to the same server and a virtual server entry in your server configuration file that uses the directory on the other drive as its doc root (using Apache?).

Comment: Because my goal is not to have the media on a sub-domain.  My goal is to move the images to a different drive.

Comment: What mean you by this then? **I plan to set this new directory as a sub-domain**

Comment: Because the media directory will no longer reside on my primary drive I will not be able to have it within the directory I have set up for the www sub-domain.  However I can configure this new directory as a new sub-domain in Apache.

Comment: When you mention _to a different drive_, is this being hosted on Linux or Windows? And also, what kind of web server, IIS or Apache? See @sonassi below for Linux handling of the problem as a second drive in Linux would be mounted to a directory mount point and putting the media folder elsewhere is a simple path change.