# CMS image is not showing properly with WYSIWYG

Tags: magento, wysiwyg

When I add an image with the WYSIWYG-editor, the image path is to long. I get the following path:

```
<img src="media url="home/magento/static/media/wysiwyg/people.png"" alt="" />
```

Instead of:

```
<img src="media url=wysiwyg/people.png"" alt="" />
```

When I import the image URL, I get in the WYSIWYG pop-up the following image URL:

The image URL is as follow: `https://server.magento.local/index.php/smladmin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9ImhvbWUvc2FuaWRpcmVjdC9zdGF0aWMvbWVkaWEvd3lzaXd5Zy9sb2dvLXBpbi5wbmcifX0,/key/acc4e19a8864aa88801f17ea0d3d8b3e/`

I think the problem has something to do with the Symlinks? Because it is only on our server, not in our local environment.

How could i solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The image src should be "wysiwyg/people.png". Check your media URL  when you try to insert an image using WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @Vikram Hi, I have updated the post with the image URL I get in the pop-up of the WYSIWYG

Comment: check in admin->system->content Management -> disable and static urls to No

Comment: The media path has been changed from OS level. Has the media directory moved from magento store to a different drive on the server ?

Comment: I have found the solutions and added as answer here. Please see the answer here below. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in another post: [How can I relocate my magento store's media directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778615/how-can-i-relocate-my-magento-stores-media-directory)

--

Can add as symbol links,
but you will get some problem with WYSIWYG editor in admin panel :)

Need following:

edit **/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php**

***function getCurrentUrl()***

```
$path = str_replace(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir(), '', $this->getCurrentPath());
```

change to

```
$path = str_replace(realpath(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir()), '', $this->getCurrentPath());
```