# How to change media upload folder (media)

Tags: magento

I have recently upgraded from Magent 1.7. to 1.8.1.0. Since then i can't see all of my uploaded folders and images inside the "media" folder when i use the Magento Image Uploader. I only see those inside "media/wysiwyg"

I checked the config.xml but the media direcotry is set correctly

```
<media>{{root_dir}}/media</media>
```

I also checked

```
Preferences -> Web -> Unsecure -> `Basis Media URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}media/`
```

The folder /media/ is set to **chmod -R 0777**

In the frontend all images are displayed correctly.

Comment: I got a backup but this is not the point. The images are still in the same place inside the media folder. For example: "media/product-pictures" or "media/category-pictures"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this post helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682834/309177

In /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php change

```
public function getStorageRoot() {
    return Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir().DS.Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Config::IMAGE_DIRECTORY.DS;
}
```

to

```
public function getStorageRoot() {
    return Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir().DS;
}
```

But this can't be the correct solution to this since in 1.7.x the code was the same and it worked.